# How to change editor background in TFVC

Tags: editor, azure-devops

I'm using Visual Studio Team Service to manage my source code. I have 2 projects.
At sections view and edit file in repository, 1 project display file by light background while another one display by dark background.

Does anyone know how to change light background?

[image: dark background]

[image: light background]

Comment: Do you mean 2 team projects or 2 projects (file) in the same team project? Do you view the page with the same Brower?

Comment: @starain-MSFT I mean I'm using 2 different team projects.

Comment: Do you use same Internet Brower?

Comment: @starain-MSFT Yeah I using the same browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the steps below:

1. Click on your account in the up-right corner and select "My profile".
2. Click "Edit profile" on the displayed page.
3. Click "Preference" tab.
4. Set UI Theme to "Default".
5. Save the changes.